# How to get the last records for a combination of 2 columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, greatest-n-per-group

I have a situation which I think can be compared to services like CamelCamelCamel, Keepa and so on. 
Lets say I track the price of an article on each day for a couple of countries. So my table, lets call it `Trend`, would look something like this

```
Id     Created      ArticleId    Country    Price
-------------------------------------------------
01     19/11/05     452          US         45.90
02     19/11/05     452          CA         52.99
03     19/11/05     452          MX         99.99
04     19/11/06     452          US         20.00
05     19/11/06     452          CA         25.00
06     19/11/06     452          MX         50.00
...                
97     19/11/05     738          US         12.99
98     19/11/05     738          CA         17.50
99     19/11/05     738          MX         45.50
```

So it's the next day and I want to update the `Trend` table. If the price in a country is still the same, I skip the article/country combination. If there is a new price I'll add a new record.

Now I want to query the table to get each `ArticleId` / `Country` combination. But only the last record of it (orderd by timestamp). So taken the example above I'd expect to get the records `04`, `05` and `06` for `ArticleId` `452`. Not `01`, `02` and `03`

So I start out with this basic query. But how do I get to change it to get my expected results?

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Trend
ORDER BY 
    Created DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method uses a correlated subquery for filtering:

```
select t.*
from trend t
where t.created = (
    select max(t1.created) 
    from trend t1
    where t1.articleId = t.articleId and t1.country = t.country
)
```

For performance, you want an index on `(articleId, country, created)`.

You might also want to consider the anti-`left join` approach:

```
select t.*
from trend t
left join trend t1 
    on  t1.articleId = t.articleId 
    and t1.country = t.country
    and t1.created > t.created
where t1.articleId is null
```

Finally, another typical solution is to join the table with an aggregate query:

```
select t.*
from trend t
inner join (
    select articleId, country, max(created) created
    from trend
    group by articleId, country
) t1 
    on  t1.articleId = t.articleId 
    and t1.country = t.country
    and t1.created = t.created
```

Which solution performs better depends on the size and distribution of your data.

Comment: Can you give an explanation which solution performs best in which scenario? A single day is about 100k of records. So the table is going to grow quickly.

Comment: @boop: it is hard to tell before hand, you shoud really test each solution against your data. If you have a large number of rows with a small number of groups (article/country tuples), the correlated subquery might offer good performance, but that's just a guess.

Comment: @boop . . . The correlated subquery with the right indexes often has the best performance or close to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a combination of `DISTINCT` and `CROSS APPLY`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ca.Id, ca.Created, t.ArticleId, t.Country, ca.Price
FROM Trend t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 Id, Created, Price
             FROM Trend
             WHERE ArticleId = t.ArticleId AND Country = t.Country
             ORDER BY Created DESC) ca
```

Often times when writing queries using `APPLY` your joining columns (`ArticleId` and `Country`) make up a unique key on another table. If this applies to your database you can drop the `DISTINCT` and speed up the query.

```
SELECT ca.Id, ca.Created, a.ArticleId, a.Country, ca.Price
FROM Article a
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 Id, Created, Price
             FROM Trend
             WHERE ArticleId = a.ArticleId AND Country = a.Country
             ORDER BY Created DESC) ca
```

Lastly, if you're having issues with performance, you may want to create an index.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NC_Trend_ArticleId] ON [Trend]
(
    [ArticleId] ASC,
    [Country] ASC,
    [Created] ASC
)
INCLUDE ([Price])
```

Presumably `Id` is a `PRIMARY KEY` and is already covered by a `CLUSTERED INDEX`, if so, the above should be appropriate for most solutions.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work just fine. Although this takes roughly about 5 times as long as a `SELECT * FROM Trend` with approx. 100k records. Can you think of another approach to get the same results?

Comment: @boop It's always going to take longer than `SELECT *` but it shouldn't take excessively long given a dataset that small. Do you have a covering index?